# variable is populating in vue function but not in template

Tags: vue.js

Fetching data from json data in vue function. Then trying to return that in my vue template. It is not returning anything on the template. But in console the variable is showing desired data. For some reason the variable is not working only on the template. 
I have used this same method to fetch and show data in other places, it worked perfectly. But here is not. 
It is not even showing any javascript error.

Here is my template:

```
    <div>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="feed in feeds" v-bind:key="feed.id">
                <h3>{{feed.title}}</h3>
                <p>{{feed.body}}</p>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the script:

```
export default {
data(){
    return {
        feeds: []
    }
},
created(){
    this.fetchFeeds();
},
methods:{
    fetchFeeds(page_url){
        let vm = this;
        page_url= page_url ||'feeds/api'
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>{
            this.feeds = res.data;
            console.log(this.feeds); //this showing data in console

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of the scope changing `this` object. 
When you call fetch() `this` does not refer to VueJs `this` object anymore. 
Just use the `vm` variable to which you assigned `this` object.

```
export default {
data(){
    return {
        feeds: []
    }
},
created(){
    this.fetchFeeds();
},
methods:{
    fetchFeeds(page_url){
        let vm = this;
        page_url= page_url ||'feeds/api'
        fetch(page_url)
       // .then(res => res.json())
        .then(function(res){
            vm.feeds = res.data;
            console.log(vm.feeds); //this showing data in console

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that already. still same problem. Showing data in console, but not in template

Comment: @Rafaeatul,  did you try to remove/comment first then from promise?

Comment: also, use full function instead of arrow

Comment: yes I did. I have noticed something very interesting actually, when I go to other page and do a cache clearing refresh, and come back to this page using back arrow, the data is showing! then when I am refreshing the page, the data is gone again!